# Parse json response and get all specific ID and store them into array then delete from shell script

Tags: arrays, json, shell, curl

I had read some of questions and answers from this forum, still not finding what I am looking for.

Here the response from curl cmd:
I would like to get all id and store them into array, then delete these IDs using `curl` cmds as well

```
 [{
     "_links": {
         "list": {
             "href": "http://10.10.10.185:8080/vndfs/lcd/v3/vdfs"
         },
         "modifyInfo": {
             "href": "http://10.10.10.185:8080/vdfs/lcd/v3/vdfs/TEST1-5cda5079a2cb47c28466bc1983f8b2e6"
         }
     },
     "description": "Purple is my color",
     "id": "TEST1-5cda5079a2cb47c28466bc1983f8b2e6"
 }, {
     "_links": {
         "list": {
             "href": "http://10.10.10.185:8080/vndfs/lcd/v3/vdfs"
         },
         "modifyInfo": {
             "href": "http://10.10.10.185:8080/vdfs/lcd/v3/vdfs/TEST2-5cda5079a2cb47c28466bc1983f8b2e6"
         }
     },
     "description": "Blue is my color",
     "id": "TEST2-5cda5079a2cb47c28466bc1983f8b2e6"
 }]
```

**getid.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
VDF=`curl -s GET http://10.10.10.185:8080/vdfs/lcd/v3/vdfs
VDFSID=`echo $VNF | python -c 'import json,sys; response=json.loads(sys.stdin.read()); print response[0]["id"]'`
echo $VDFSID
```

**output from echo:**

```
TEST1-5cda5079a2cb47c28466bc1983f8b2e6
```

but I want to get all all id and store the into array, then I can delete each `TEST1-XX` and `TEST2-XXX` id

```
for i in response['id']:
     curl -XDELETE http://10.10.10.185:8080/vdfs/lcd/v3/vdfs/$i
```

any advises for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) JSON parser with `xarg` to inject the results into `curl` :

```
curl -s -X GET http://10.10.10.185:8080/vdfs/lcd/v3/vdfs | \
    jq -r ' .[] | .id ' | \
    xargs -I {} curl -X DELETE http://10.10.10.185:8080/vdfs/lcd/v3/vdfs/{}
```

This will extract `id` from your JSON array and make successive call to curl per id with the url `http://10.10.10.185:8080/vdfs/lcd/v3/vdfs/<ID>`

You can also use [`jsontool`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsontool) for parsing JSON (install with npm) :

```
curl -s -X GET http://10.10.10.185:8080/vdfs/lcd/v3/vdfs | \
    json -a id | \
    xargs -I {} curl -X DELETE http://10.10.10.185:8080/vdfs/lcd/v3/vdfs/{}
```

Comment: Thanks. my OS is not supported jq. I thought about it because I had seen some example but your is more details. any alternate for jq? -mjson.tool from python, but it only formats your output.

Comment: You can also use [jsontool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsontool), see my updated post

Comment: i just downloaded jq-linux64 portable and copied over my OS. i can use it. Thanks.